# Использование ЧПУ при работе с Kohana

Tags: framework, mvc, kohana, php

Ни в какую не хочет убираться index.php с этой ссылки

> `"http://mydomen.ua/test/kohana/index.php/bravo"`

Если так пишу, то браузер выдает содержимое контроллера bravo.php, там, допустим, `Hello and Bravo` написано, а если убираю index.php, т.е. `http://mydomen.ua/test/kohana/bravo`, то переходит вообще на непонятную страницу, очень напоминающую ту, которая находится на главной сайта mydomen.ua (единственное, что изменено в ней, так это цвет бэкграунда одно из элементов, это не так важно, конечно, но тоже странно), дело в том, что класс контроллера я назвал правильно:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Bravo extends Controller {

    public function action_index()
    {
        $this->response->body('Hello and Bravo');
    }

} // End Welcome
```

и в файле bootstrap.php тоже в конце прописал:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'bravo',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Но не перекидывает меня на нужную страницу, не знаю, что еще тут не так может быть?

Comment: > Kohana, вопрос про ЧПУ?
> Да.

*Привет от Grammar Nazi =)*

Comment: я бы зарифмовал, но боюсь что меня забанят.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот тебе в помощь.](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/tutorials/clean-urls) У меня всегда всё работало.

Comment: да, я тоже решил, надо было правильно пути прописать в .htaccess и bootstrap'э, просто я установил в подкаталог test/ главного сайта kohana, а не как отдельный сайт.

Comment: ну base_url и RewriteBasse указываешь как /test/ и всё ок будет.